# Increase variable value with a method call

Tags: java, android, widget

I'm building a simple widget to display a number every day. I initialized a class called Counter and its getter and setter and use them to increase the value. However, every time the `onUpdate()` method is called (30 minute period, the widget is updated), the variable resets to 1.

```
public class WidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {
Counter counter = new Counter();
//Create class counter in order to store global variable
//Constructor makes the counter value = 1
int k;
@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {

    for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {
        k=counter.getI();
        // k now equals to 1 
        Toast.makeText(context, "Widget has been updated! ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);
        views.setCharSequence(R.id.button, "setText",""+k); //1
        counter.increase(counter.getI());
        //Log shows counter value = 2
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
    }
}
```

Can you please help me fix this or suggest another way? :( Thank you guys very much.

Comment: What's `Counter` look like?

Comment: http://pasted.co/b49173f2 like this. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should never expect instance variables in an AppWidgetProvider to be persistent. Most likely your AppWidgetProvider is getting destroyed after the update and will be recreated the next time an update is needed. When this happens, you'll get a new copy of Counter with a value of 1.

If you want a value to be remembered between widget updates, you should store that value in persistent storage, SharedPreferences for example.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

Comment: Thank you very much! I will take a look into it.